# Date Detection program gone wrong

Tags: python, regex, function

I am a novice working on a short program with the purpose of detecting dates and printing out whether the given dates are valid or not. Here's how it looks like :

```
dateRegex = re.compile(r'''(
     (0[1-9]|[12]\d|30|31)
     [.\\ /]
     (0[1-9]|1[0-2])
     [.\\ /]
     ([1-2][0-9]{3})
     )''', re.VERBOSE)

def dateValidation(date):
    text = str(pyperclip.paste())
    mo = date.findall(text)
    for groups in mo:
       day = groups[1]
       month = groups[2]
       year = groups[3]
       leapyear = ''
       if (  month == '04' or month == '06' or month == '09' or month == '11'  ) and ( int(day) > 30 ):
           print(f'The {groups[0]} string is not a date.')
           continue
       if int(year) % 4 == 0:
           leapyear += year
       if int(year) % 100 == 0:
           leapyear = ''
       if ( int(year) % 100 == 0 ) and ( int(year) % 400 == 0 ):
           leapyear += year
       if  month == '02'  and leapyear == year:
           if int(day) > 29:
               print(f'The {groups[0]} string is not a date.')
               continue
       elif month == '02' and leapyear != year:
           if int(day) > 28:
               print(f'The {groups[0]} string is not a date.')
               continue
       print(f'The {groups[0]} string is a date.')


dateValidation(dateRegex)
```

I know a lot of the code isn't clean or practical, so I'm open to suggestions about optimizing it, of course ( I'm fairly new to this after all, and apparently doing horribly ), but the question is mainly regarding the output of the program.

I copied 01.02.2016 21.6.2003 26.7.1999 to clipboard and expected to get a result regarding all three dates. Instead, the output was only ''The 01.02.2016 string is a date.'' Did I overlook something ? What could've gone wrong ?

If it isn't obvious from the code, here is a detailed description of what the program is supposed to do :

**Write a regular expression that can detect dates in the DD/MM/YYYY format. Assume that the days range from 01 to 31, the months range from 01 to 12, and the years range from 1000 to 2999. Note that if the day or month is a single digit, it’ll have a leading zero.
The regular expression doesn’t have to detect correct days for each month or for leap years; it will accept nonexistent dates like 31/02/2020 or 31/04/2021. Then store these strings into variables named month, day, and year, and write additional code that can detect if it is a valid date. April, June, September, and November have 30 days, February has 28 days, and the rest of the months have 31 days. February has 29 days in leap years. Leap years are every year evenly divisible by 4, except for years evenly divisible by 100, unless the year is also evenly divisible by 400. Note how this calculation makes it impossible to make a reasonably sized regular expression that can detect a valid date.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using an IDE now is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the regular expression follows from the format of the dates in the text. Since some of the dates are given as 21.6.2003 and not 21.06.2003, your regex misses that.

For the dates you can use the following one:

`r'(0*[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\.(0*[0-9]|1[0-2])\.[1-2][0-9]{3})'`

Here,

- `(0*[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])` matches the days ranging in `00-31`. In the first case, `0*` tells regex to match *zero* or more of the preceding token. So, if the date is given in `06` or `6` format, it can catch both cases
- Similar approach also follows in `(0*[0-9]|1[0-2])`, which finds the month in the range `00-12`